# AI: How to find an evaluation function in this game (minimax algo)?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am thinking about an AI for a game that I could implement. My question is about finding an evaluation function for this game in order to apply the minimax algorithm with alpha/beta cuts.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning
Let me describe the game first, explain what I plan to achieve with my AI, and get to the problem.

**The game:**

```
A 2-player turn-by-turn game.
Goal is to kill opponent or have more life points at the end.
In comparison with Magic: The Gathering, you both have monsters to attack the opponent. The number is fixed, let’s say 5 each.
A monster has a fight ability (let's say between 1 and 10), and a damage ability (let's say between 1 and 5).

Each turn:
- Active player declares to his opponent which monster (he owns) engages the current fight.
- He secretly sets multipliers face down (let’s see that in next paragraph).
- Opponent declares which monster (he owns) fights against the first one, while setting multipliers the same way.
- Fight: fight ability * multipliers = final attack. Biggest attack wins and inflicts damage ability to opponent.
- Next turn, active player switch

About multipliers: you have 4 cards in hand that can double your attack (and many empty cards, so that you put 4 cards each turn on the table, and the opponent does not know if you multiplied by 1, 2, 4, 8 or 16).
Just in case: let's say we have a rule for draws to be solved.
```

What I expect with the AI:
To be able to say if a perfect player should win in a given position. That means, for a winnable position, AI should tell that there is a way that leads to victory, and give the steps (see example below). For a position that is a winnable by the opponent, I have not decided yet, neither for positions that do not lead to the same winner in all cases (they exist ;D).

** An example: **

```
2 rounds left to go. I have
- Monster A: fight: 5, damage: 2
- Monster B: fight: 3, damage: 4
- life: 5, 1 multiplier left, my turn to begin
My opponent has
- Monster C: fight: 2, damage: 6
- Monster D: fight: 8, damage: 1
-life: 5, 1 multiplier left

In that case, if you think about it, you win if you play well.
Solution:
You can see that if monster C wins, he inflicts 6 and I lost.
But if he loses, one my monsters will inflict at least 2, and even if monster D wins (before or after),
I won't die and I will have more life that my opponent. Victory.
That's an example of what I want the AI to find.
```

Of course, I simplified the example. Maybe it can be trickier. And that's where my question arrives.

We can mentally kind of see that it is simple to calculate all possible duels when we have 2 rounds left (the last round does not need calculation: it is deterministic if both play their last multipliers).
As we said, we have 5 rounds to go. But my point is that we could have 20, and it becomes very long to calculate everything (as in trying to find best move in first round).
Indeed, we won't try to compute that. In chess, for instance, too many positions lead to the impossibility of computing all possibilities.

But, if you follow me, there is a solution in chess - we can implement an evaluation function. How do we know that 10 moves ahead, this moves leads to a better position ? Because we evaluate this position. We claim that a position is better if it's checkmate, obviously, or if you have more pieces, or if you control the center and so on...

Then, my question here:

**How to evaluate a position in the game I presented ?**

I mean, first round, if I can compute the possible moves in the 2 next rounds, I arrive at all possible positions for round 3 or 4. But it does not seem to help in my opinion. You can have better life points, better cards, more left multipliers, it all depends on what will arrive next. I don't see advantages that are compliant in general situations. What about you ?

N.B.1 I hope it was clear, I simplified game rules, of course we could add rules (combo if 2 consecutive rounds won, multipliers applicable to damage ability...)

N.B.2 I thought about a neural network, but the question is still interesting for me. And a neural network seems hard to settle because of the multiple rounds (my knowledge is far more restricted than knowing any model with retroactive action in a neural network).

N.B.3 I think that minimax and alpha/beta cuts will help if I still do a full computation analysis, but what I am afraid of is computation time, that's why I ask this here. I could probably begin with complete computation for last-2-round positions, yes.

Thanks for reading, and I hope you find this problem as stimulating as I do!

Comment: Your goal is more to solve the game than to play it convincingly?

Comment: Actually yeah, because I played it before ^^' A similar version of what I described.

Comment: Assuming no negative monster values, you basically only have 4*4*yourhealth*opponenthealth possible game states. Sounds like a problem well suited for dynamic programming.

Comment: For a given round, is also included the remaining multipliers, and extra rules if I add them! But thanks, I'll look into that

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but I'm concerned that it may be either too broad or off-topic for this specific site. Is there possibly a different SE where it might attract more knowledgeable answers? I'm thinking datascience.SE or scicomp.SE or stats.SE ...

Comment: You think ? I actually hesitated a lot on where to put this question! Maybe datascience...

Answer (score 1):

One way to evaluate the position in any game is to try to understand the thinking process of players who are considered experts in the game. So you can find experts in this game and ask them about factors that determine their decisions during the game. Or you can become an expert yourself by studying the game and playing it a lot. It can be very hard to come up with a good evaluation function by just looking at the rules of the game.

I haven't played this game, but probably it makes sense to start with some simple heuristic which is a linear combination of variables that determine the game state (health points of your main character, number of multipliers you have, total fight/damage ability of all your monsters, maximum fight/damage ability of any of your monsters, number of turns left  etc). Take into account the corresponding values for your opponent and you'll get the eval function like this: `a1*(my_hp - opp_hp) + a2*(my_monsters_total_fight - opp_monsters_total_fight) + a3*(my_monsters_total_damage - opp_monsters_total_damage) + a4*(my_number_of_multipliers - opp_number_of_multipliers) + ...`, where coefficients `a1,a2,..` can be positive or negative depending on the effect of corresponding variable (for instance, coefficient of `hp` variable `a1` is positive etc.)

Now, this function might or might not work, but at least it will give you a starting point from which you can try to improve it or completely discard if it fails miserably. You can try to improve this evaluation function by tuning the coefficients, adding some non-linear terms to produce more complex relationships between the variables (multiplications, powers, logs etc.) and see how it affects performance. You can also try to automate the tuning process by using optimization techniques like genetic algorithms and differential evolution. In general, coming up with a good heuristic can be more an art than a science (after all, it's called heuristic for a reason). Start by trial and error and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks. So what I see is that you set the problem in a way it could be put in a neural network then. Interesting. So I would need data of many battles to train it